# Ruby AWS SNS SDK: unexpected option message_attributes

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm trying to publish a message to an endpoint using ruby's sdk for aws sns. The documentation suggests that I can add TTL to the message attributes. However, the following code gives an argument error exception:

```
# ArgumentError:
#  unexpected option message_attributes

@client.publish(:target_arn => endpoint_arn,
    :subject => title,
    :message_structure => "json",
    :message => get_message(title, message).to_json,
    :message_attributes => {
      "AWS.SNS.MOBILE.APNS.TTL" => {
        :data_type => "String",
        :string_value => TTL_SECONDS
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This option isn't available in older versions of the api. Upgrading to the newest version (1.48.1) solved the problem.